# Is there a NULL equivalent for pairs in C++?

Tags: c++, std-pair

What would I want to use instead of NULL if I have an unassigned pair in C++?

As an example, suppose I have (pseudo)code like the following:

```
pair<int,int> bestPair; //Global variable

updateBestPair(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {

    bestPair = NULL;

    for (/* loop through a and b */) {
        if (/* pair(a,b) is better than bestPair and better than some baseline */)
            bestPair = make_pair(a,b);
    }

    if (bestPair != NULL) //Found an acceptable best pair
        function(bestPair);
    else
        cout<<"No acceptable pairs found"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a NULL equivalent for pairs in C++?

No.

> What would I want to use instead of NULL if I have an unassigned pair in C++?

Here are a few options:

- you can use a pointer to a pair, which can be set to NULL; This is probably not the best solution (since you are clearly not requiring a pointer)
- you can use a `boost::optional<std::pair<int,int>>`;
- you can (and probably *should*) rewrite your code not to use a global variable.
- you can restructure your control flow to avoid checking for a valid pair as a separate step:

  ```
  pair<int,int> bestPair; //Global variable

  updateBestPair(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {

      // not needed
      // bestPair = NULL;

      //loop through a and b
      if (/* pair(a,b) is better than bestPair and ... */)
      {
          bestPair = make_pair(a,b);
          function(bestPair);
      }
      else
          cout<<"No acceptable pairs found"<<endl;
  }
  ```
- you can choose an artificial value to represent "invalid pair value":

  ```
  // use as constant, wherever you used NULL before
  const auto invalid_pair = std::make_pair(
      std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
      std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
  ```
- you can use a boolean flag:

  ```
  pair<int,int> bestPair; //Global variable

  updateBestPair(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {

      bool initialized = false;

      //loop through a and b
      if (/* pair(a,b) is better than bestPair and ... */)
      {
          bestPair = make_pair(a,b);
          initialized = true;
      }

      if(initialized)
          function(bestPair);
      else
          cout<<"No acceptable pairs found"<<endl;
  }
  ```
- you can use a custom solution (similar to boost::optional wrapper or not)

Comment: Your first code suggestion leaves `bestPair` in an "invalid state" with no variable denoting that fact. Given that `bestPair` is a global variable, it is most likely used elsewhere; therefore, this suggestion is unlikely to be a feasible approach. The rest is all good :)

Comment: I assumed that the bestPair had a valid value before calling into `updateBestPair`, due to the function being named **update**BestPair, not **init**BestPair (my bad - I had no reasons to assume).

Comment: Thanks, these are all really good ideas! I think using boost::optional would be the cleanest method, and that using a boolean flag would be the easiest (though also the easiest to screw up later on). I can't use artificial values for this particular application since any pair values are acceptable, though that's the approach I usually prefer. And yeah, not using a global variable would be the best, but in this case that would require rewriting the whole framework, so that goes on a to-do list for whenever I do a major restructuring!

Comment: @utnapistim: Fair enough I suppose but I'd expect a function named **updateBestPair** that didn't update `bestPair` to tell me that somehow :P And I don't just mean with a console message.

Comment: @user1634426, the implementation of boost::optional is effectively the storage for an automatic storage variable of the given type, and a bool flag to specify if the value was initialized (and the code to keep them synchronized).

Answer (score 5):

No. C++ objects cannot be "NULLed".

*(Even pointers, which are objects, cannot be "NULLed"! This is confusing because their value may be set to a null pointer value, which we sometimes in the past obtained with a macro named `NULL`; however, this has never been the same as "NULLing" the pointer itself. Er, anyway…)*

I recommend either `boost::optional`, or rethink the idea of having a global variable that can be "has a useful value" or "does not have a useful value". What's the point in it existing if it has no useful value?

Comment: Wow, the boost::optional package looks like exactly what I need! Thanks!

As for why I need a global variable like this in the first place - I'm doing some particle physics analysis where I need to read in a ton of collision events. Sometimes I find a relevant electron collision parameter, and sometimes I'll have collisions that don't have enough good electrons. However, in the second case I can't just go to the next event. I have to do the analysis still, just marking down somewhere that I didn't find a good electron pair.

Comment: @user1634426: Alright. In the olden days I'd have done as Marius suggests, then; `boost::optional` is the quicker/atomic way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. You could use an additional variable to indicate the validity of the pair (that you have a pair).

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea. I prefer a way not to have to use two variables for a single purpose (easy for the two to lose sync), but I guess sometimes it's the best solution.